# ember template can't find my custom helper

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, emblem.js

I created a helper called graph-helper.coffee which will compile to js. When it compiles, it successfully creates the js copy of the helper graph-helper.js, but in my template, when I do {{graph-helper ___ ____}} the console tells me:

```
"Assertion Failed: A helper named "graph-helper" could not be found"
name
```

here is my coffee file

```
Ember.Helper.helper (params) ->
arg1 = parseFloat(params[0]);
arg2 = parseFloat(params[1]);

return arg1 * arg2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`export default  Ember.Helper.helper` - you need to export it to default so that it will be available to use